# Fill in vector with new values and shift to the left

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a permanent vector and add new values (scalars) until the vector is full. Then all new values x will replace the last one and shift left all the others by 1 so the first value of the vector gets out of it. At the beginning the vector is empty.

**UPDATE**

> So at the beginning the vector is empty []
>
> When I run the function the first time it would be like this (x=1): 1
>
> After running the function 10 times will be like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> Next time will be like this: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
>
> and so on: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

x is just a new value not progressive as above.

This is what I have done so far but I get errors

```
function [ b ] = buffer( x )

persistent A;
A = int16.empty(10,0); % preallocate
for pos=1:10
   [ A(1:pos) x A((pos+1):end) ];
    b=A

 end
```

> Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Error in buffer (line 14)    [
>   A(1:pos) x A((pos+1):end) ];

Since I have  gray hair this is not homework but curiosity in learning something new on my own. Some help to sort this out will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a loop? I don't get it.

Comment: @Kamtal is the way thought I should have done it. No other reasons.

Comment: Since in every call we are just adding a number to `A` I don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right then this code will help,

```
function b = buffer(x) 
persistent A;
if isempty(A)
    A = int16.empty(1,0); % preallocate
end
A = [A x];
if length(A) > 10
    A(1 : length(A) -10) = [];
end
b = A;
end
```

A simpler way would be this,

```
function b = buffer(x)
persistent A;
if isempty(A)
    A = zeros(1,10); % preallocate
end
A = [A(2:end) x];
b = A; 
end
```

if you don't mind the zeros while `A` is not filled.

Comment: This works nicely. But I need to move to the left not to the right. Basically first in first out

Comment: You are a star. Thanks a lot for it. Now I understand the logic.